# Does OpenGL fixed-function lighting use "vertex-to-eye" dotted with "vertex-to-light" to compute specular intensity?

Tags: opengl, graphics

According to the man page on my system and this MSDN page here:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373927(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373927%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> The specular light source contribution is the product of the material
>   specular reflectance, the light's specular intensity, and the dot
>   product of the normalized **vertex-to-eye and vertex-to-light** vectors,
>   raised to the power of the shininess of the material.

Everything I read about Phong says that the specular intensity is computed by dotting vertex-to-eye with vertex-to-reflection vector... and that OpenGL instead chose Blinn's simplification of dotting vertex-normal with half-vector... so what is all this nonsense about  dotting vertex-to-eye with vertex-to-light?  That would produce the worst lighting in the world, right?  Is it a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That description doesn't sound right. It wouldn't even use the normal vector, and calculating specular lighting without taking the normal vector into account doesn't make any sense.

You can find the correct description in the Red Book, which is available online. Look for "Specular Term" under this section: http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter05.html#name7. In short, it matches the Blinn-Phong model you expected. It defines a vector `s` as the normalized sum of "vertex to light" and "vertex to viewpoint", which is the half-vector. It then calculates the dot product of this vector `s` with the normal vector, and multiplies it with the light/material constants.